# How do I GZIP the merged JS file?

Tags: configuration, javascript, performance, gzip

I noticed when I merge the CSS/JS files then enable Gzip in the htaccess, JS doesn't compress. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Update: Htaccess File Content

```
############################################
## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

#    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
#    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

############################################
## GoDaddy specific options

#   Options -MultiViews

## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

############################################
## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

    #AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
    #AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

############################################
## default index file

    DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>

############################################
## adjust memory limit

#    php_value memory_limit 64M
    php_value memory_limit 256M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################
## disable magic quotes for php request vars

    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

    php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## enable resulting html compression

    php_flag zlib.output_compression on

###########################################
# disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

###########################################
# turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects

    php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
###########################################
# disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

    # Insert filter on all content
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Insert filter on selected content types only
    #AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Don't compress images
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

############################################
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

    SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase /magento/

############################################
## uncomment next line to enable light API calls processing

#    RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]

############################################
## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

############################################
## redirect for mobile user agents

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>


############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

   ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>

############################################
## By default allow all access

   # Order allow,deny
   # Allow from all

###########################################
## Deny access to release notes to prevent disclosure of the installed Magento version

    <Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
        #order allow,deny
        #deny from all
    </Files>

############################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

    #FileETag none

############################################
## turn on the module for this directory
ExpiresActive on
# set default
ExpiresDefault "access plus 24 hours"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 months"
```

Comment: Could you show the configuration you did to expect gzip compression?

Comment: ksangers, I have modified the post to include the htaccess contents.

Comment: Looks fine at first glance, so just to be sure: did you enable mod_deflate?

Comment: Yes, I have just checked and it's enabled. It's so strange, I cannot figure out why JS isn't compressed.

Comment: Okay, could you show me the request (should have Accept-Encoding) and response headers for one of these JS files?

Comment: Here is the request header `Request URL:http://our-site.com/media/js/29c15708b9e7394a21f8e1870fcd7674.js
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK (from cache)`

Comment: @PaulDonnelly What's your methodology for determining the Javascript isn't compressed?

Comment: Hi Alan, when I run PageSpeed and YSlow both are saying to enable gzip. I am assuming from this that they are not compressed. Do you know of any other tests I can run?

Comment: @PaulDonnelly This article has a way to test things with curl http://dev.nuclearrooster.com/2009/11/08/checking-gzipdeflate-server-responses-with-curl/

Comment: @PaulDonnelly Also, this may be of interest.  Apparently YSlow doesn't detect gzip compression correctly http://blog.oasic.net/2010/06/beware-of-yslow-and-gzip.html

Comment: Hi Alan, Thanks for this. I will have a look into it and let you know the results.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an answer that Allan Storm gave someone on StackOverflow (credit goes to him):

When Magento merges any CSS and Javascript files that pass through its rendering system, it will create URLs for those resource like this, and add them to the head of the page

```
http://magento1point6point1.dev/media/css/a438f0287fdd0c52d9bd196d355a63c3.css
http://magento1point6point1.dev/media/js/0567fb98ebe279ea4faf5acf433fc6a1.js
```

in turn, this will generate files on the filesystem

```
media/css/a438f0287fdd0c52d9bd196d355a63c3.css
media/js/0567fb98ebe279ea4faf5acf433fc6a1.js
```

At this point, Magento is removed from the process almost completely (there's a `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/` in `.htaccess` to catch non-existant files). It sounds like you have gzip compression setup correctly for other areas of the site. So, however you've configured other folders for gzip compression, configure `media/css` and `media/js` to do the same.

To read the whole question read: [Gzip on merged CSS/JS files in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437041/gzip-on-merged-css-js-files-in-magento)

Answer (score 2):

I did following modifications and i dont get notification by Google Speed after for gzip after i edited line as follow.

Add application/x-httpd-php in AddOutputFilterByType part of .htaccess, so it look like as following,

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/x-httpd-php
```

Answer (score 1):

There is Magento's default **`merge CSS and JS`** feature which looks great, but I found a bug on Magento 1.6 (or may be only me) which is, after you enable default merge settings Shopping Cart Rules could not be added.

Then I thought of using [Fooman Speedster Module](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/fooman-speedster.html) which looked like a great plugin over 50K downloads. It is great, this plugin not only merge all the CSS and `JS` but also minifies, which will in some amount reduce the file size as well and the issue I noted with default merge did not arise. Though it is a bit difficult to setup, this looks like a great module and I have been running shops with this plugin for a long time.

And for the compression part, you could work out that from `.htaccess` the link shared above [Compression Part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437041/gzip-on-merged-css-js-files-in-magento) is great.